# Why my ClusterIP does not work with the ip assigned?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, calico

I have defined a new service with a ClusterIP.

```
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>          443/TCP          4d1h    
test-reg     ClusterIP      10.102.196.35   <none>          5000/TCP         58m
test-web     LoadBalancer   10.108.151.13   192.168.1.125   80:30001/TCP     73m
```

The pod is running on worker-node1 and I can connect to this server with the worker-node1 plumbed on ethernet ip.

```
[ciuffoly@worker-node1 ~]$ ip addr show|grep "192\.168\.1\."
inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute ens33

[ciuffoly@worker-node1 ~]$ telnet 192.168.1.20 5000    
Connected to 192.168.1.20.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q

[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ telnet 192.168.1.20 5000
Connected to 192.168.1.20.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q
```

But I cannot connect to this service with the ClusterIP

```
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ telnet 10.102.196.35 5000
Trying 10.102.196.35...
^C
```

Following the answers I have tested also NodePort but I still have the same problem.

```
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ kubectl get services|grep reg
test-reg     NodePort       10.111.117.116   <none>          5000:30030/TCP   5m41s

[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ kubectl delete svc test-reg
service "test-reg" deleted
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ netstat -an|grep 30030

[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ kubectl apply -f myreg.yaml
myreg.yamldeployment.apps/test-reg unchanged
service/test-reg created
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ netstat -an|grep 30030
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30030           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

This does not work

```
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ telnet master-node  30030
Trying 192.168.1.10...
^C
```

This works

```
[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ telnet worker-node1  30030
Trying 192.168.1.20...
Connected to worker-node1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

Comment: ClusterIP is valid inside the cluster. So you need to get inside a Pod and use telnet to use that ClusterIP

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

Comment: ok, but there is a method to create a logical ip that I can connect from master and all workers ? I would like to use this for the local register

Comment: I see you have a LoadBalancer service with attached an External IP. What is it attached to? Can you describe (kubectl descrive resource-type resource-name) the service and the Pod you are trying to reach?

Comment: SOLVED  All problem has been solved using Calico instead of Flannel

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already confirmed by andrea ciuffoli, switching from Flannel to Calico solved the issue.

Flannel is a very simple overlay network that satisfies the Kubernetes requirements.

On the other hand, Calico is an open source networking and network security solution for containers, virtual machines, and native host-based workloads. Calico supports multiple data planes including: a pure Linux eBPF dataplane, a standard Linux networking dataplane, and a Windows HNS dataplane. Calico provides a full networking stack but can also be used in conjunction with [cloud provider CNIs](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/determine-best-networking#calico-compatible-cni-plugins-and-cloud-provider-integrations) to provide network policy enforcement.

It's hard to say what was the sole reason behind the final solution but you can find some details about [Comparing Kubernetes CNI Providers: Flannel, Calico, Canal, and Weave](https://rancher.com/blog/2019/2019-03-21-comparing-kubernetes-cni-providers-flannel-calico-canal-and-weave/).

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types):

> The service type `ClusterIP` exposes the Service on a cluster-internal
> IP. Choosing this value makes the Service **only** reachable from
> **within** the cluster. This is the default ServiceType.

So you can reach your ClusterIP service only from within your cluster. So you could deploy a pod with telnet installed and test your setup from there.

If you want to connect from your host, you could use the service type [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
```

This way you could connect to the service via `hostname:30080`. The thing is, that you can use every hostname of your cluster.

Comment: now work!

[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
test-reg     NodePort       10.102.196.35   <none>          5000:30030/TCP   148m


[ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ telnet 10.102.196.35 30030
Trying 10.102.196.35...
^C

Comment: Take into consideration that using NodePort is not resilient to node failure as much as using a LoadBalancer service. LoadBalancer services are the type of service to use if HA and resilience needs to come into play.

Comment: ok, but both NodePort and LoadBalancer does not work from mater-node

Comment: @AndD that is correct. But in most onprem setups you don't have a LoadBalancer out of the box.

Comment: @andreaciuffoli: don't use the clusterIP for telnet on your host. Use the hostname or the nodes IP. e.g. `telnet master-node 30080` (or which port you are using...)

Comment: [ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ telnet master-node 30030
Trying 192.168.1.10...
not run!

Comment: [ciuffoly@master-node ~]$ netstat -an|grep 30030
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30030           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: @andreaciuffoli using it directly from the own host seems not to work (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67730#issuecomment-818575890) or takes sometimes very long (>1min). What is your usecase? Maybe we can find another solution. Inside your k8s cluster network your service will be reachable via the service name.

Comment: I would to create a service for the local register to use for docker images so master-node and worker-nodes should connect the register in the pod.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I would like to have a local register for my custom docker images instead of use the https://hub.docker.com/repository

Comment: You could deploy your registry in kubernetes (which can lead to a chicken-egg problem) with an ingress placed before. So you could pull and push from outside (an inside) of your cluster the images. Or you can deploy the registry in a dedicated environment. But this probably is not in focus of this question

Comment: Today I have tested also with Ingress and same result: the master-node cannot contact the virtual ip created by the Ingress just like the LoabBalancer configuration

Comment: SOLVED  All problem has been solved using Calico instead of Flannel

Comment: Good to hear that. Please provide a separate answer explaining the actions taken in order to solve your issue or edit the one above with the same info

Comment: Also with Calico it is necessary close the firewall to run without problems.  I have read about strange packages that are locked by iptables but there is no solution to solve this.